# how to Load an image from side in html using css

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I have been working with w3.css and html and have built a web pages using w3.css div, etc.  The page loads text images, it use fading, and other features.

However I noticed some sites have images that load from the right side (like a transition) - can this be done with w3.css.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve] by clicking the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: RTM: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w3.css has already the possibility to animate elements built-in. 
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_animate.asp

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.slower {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s !important;
  animation-duration: 2.5s!important;
}
</style>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h1 class="w3-center w3-animate-right">Animation is Fun!</h1>
</div>

<!-- Slower Animation by adding additional class with overwrite -->
<div class="w3-container">
  <h1 class="w3-center w3-animate-right slower">Animation is Fun!</h1>
</div>
```

You could also use a external CSS animation library like animate.css
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Works, Is there a way to make it load slower?. Thanks

Comment: I updated the solution and added a class to animate slower. Tough overwriting the style with !important is not ideal i dit not found another possibility in w3.css to control the speed.